# ssc_interface published from autoware how to subscribe it from pacmod?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed this https://github.com/Autoware-AI/autoware.ai/issues/1944 but can not subscribe to the ssc_interface from pacmod.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356673/ssc_interface-published-from-autoware-how-to-subscribe-it-from-pacmod?/) by [sudip](https://answers.ros.org/users/55839/sudip/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ssc_interface` is designed to produce messages which are consumed by the Speed and Steering Controller (SSC) software from AutonomouStuff. This software then sends the commands to PACMod. There is currently no direct interface between Autoware.AI and PACMod but we'd be happy to have someone develop one! (at least until the end of the year, when we stop accepting new features for Autoware.AI).

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1